# physicsBody.applyImpulse & collision happening twice instead of once

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Heres the deal. My ball drops, hits the floor, and bounces back up with the help of the following code

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 25))
```

However, sometimes the ball recognises two collisions instead of one (on impact) and the ball gets applyImpulse x2. (Due to lag or something?) Causing the ball to fly way to fast. How do i make sure the ball doesn't collide with the floor twice? The ball is 16x16 an the floor is 16x160. I didn't have this problem earlier when the ball and floor were larger. But i really want to solve the problem and it must be possible!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the ball is not moving fast enough between updates to be off the paddle before the next update check.

Remember what we did for the boss?  Same thing gets applied to the paddle.  When the ball hits the paddle,  remove the contact check for it.  Now you are going to have to add another node in, so that when you pass this node, you reenable  the paddle check

Comment: I decided to drop the balls below the boss instead, because i needed to spawn a bunch of balls in quick succession, which caused the boss collision to freak out when it had 2 balls colliding at the same time.

I actually manage to solve this new problem by increasing the height of the paddle.SKPhysicsBody to 64 instead of 16. It doesn't really matter because you don't see it anyway. So its fine

Comment: two balls colliding at the same time caused issues?  you must have messed something up

Comment: No, let me re-explain that - There was an issue when balls spawned too fast. One ball spawned, touched the paddle, "activating the boss", then another ball spawned before the first ball had hit the boss to de-activate it. That caused the second ball to damage the boss by just spawning inside it

Comment: yes you messed up,  the activation deactivation state is per ball, not global

Comment: Well thats a relief to know that its possible to create unique (self/this) object statements. I'm curious about the boss however, he's a single unit. His activation-state must affect other balls in a weird way even though the balls are all unique entities? In other words - a single ball can change the boss activation state affecting the other balls. Right?

Comment: you would have to come up with another condition,  check my answer again on your original post